# How can I define a set of values for the NotEqualTo constraint?

Tags: symfony, validation

When using the [NotEqualTo validator constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/NotEqualTo.html), I want to define more than one value.

This is how it is used for one value:

```
# src/SocialBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\SocialBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        age:
            - NotEqualTo:
                value: 15
```

But how can I define a set (an array) of values? I tried

```
            - NotEqualTo:
                value: 15
                value: 16
                value: 17
```

and

```
            - NotEqualTo:
                value: [15, 16, 17]
```

but both approaches didn't work.

Comment: In the documentation I read this: `value: This option is required. It defines the value to compare to. It can be a string, number or object.` 
Have you tried to pass an object `{...}`?

Comment: You have to use validation groups - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

Comment: @Lughino Unfortunately there is no further explanation about how to pass the object or how to define it I did not try that.

Comment: @repincln I was looking for an quick and easy way to define more than one value without the necessity to use validation groups. But thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can have more than one constraint.

```
Acme\SocialBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        age:
            - NotEqualTo: { value: 15 }
            - NotEqualTo: { value: 16 }
            - NotEqualTo: { value: 17 }
```

Or provide a callback validator

```
Acme\SocialBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        age:
            - Callback: [validateNotOfAge]
```

.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\SocialBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class Person
{
    public function validateNotOfAge(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (in_array($this->age, array(
            15, 16, 17
        ))) {
            $context->addViolationAt(
                'age',
                'This age is not permitted',
                array(),
                null
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Or if you have Symfony 2.4, you can use the new `Expression` validator which uses the ExpressionLanguage component.

```
Acme\SocialBundle\Entity\Person:
    properties:
        age:
            - Expression:
                expression: "this.getAge() not in [15, 16, 17]"
```

Comment: A very helpful and comprehensive answer. Thanks!

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel you're welcome. btw, I've corrected the Callback example, as I forgot to use the ExecutionContext.